# Java concurrency using ConcurrentHashMap with synchronized block

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, java.util.concurrent, concurrenthashmap

Here is my main class that initializes and starts 5 different Threads:

```
public class Server implements Runnable {
    Server1 server1;
    Thread server1Thread;

    public Server() {}

    @Override
    public void run() {
        server1 = new Server1();
        server1Thread = new Thread(server1);
        server1Thread.start();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            Server s = new Server();
            s.run();
        }
    }
}
```

Here is my `Server1` Runnable:

```
import java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap;
public class Server1 implements Runnable {
    private ConcurrentHashMap<Integer, Integer> storage= new ConcurrentHashMap<>();

    public Server1() {}

    @Override
    public void run() {
        synchronized (this){
            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
                storage.put(i, (int)(Math.random()*100));
            }
            for (int i : storage.keySet()) {
                System.out.print("(" + i + "," + storage.get(i) + ") ");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
}
```

It puts in `ConcurrentHashMap storage` keys from `0` to `9` and assigns them a random value between `0` and `100`. After that it prints it and prints new line at the end. I have user `synchronized` block to make sure the thread itself access keys correctly but it prints something like this:

```
(0,8) (0,87) (1,60) (1,14) (2,20) (2,70) (3,5) (0,74) (0,42) (1,22) (4,96) (0,85) (1,97) (2,75) (3,68) (4,3) (5,49) (6,3) (7,9) (8,47) (9,52) 
(3,2) (5,74) (2,86) (1,48) (3,5) (6,0) (4,0) (7,86) (4,22) (8,20) (2,17) (9,87) 
(5,96) (5,15) (6,15) (6,92) (7,48) (8,93) (9,67) 
(3,87) (7,43) (4,34) (5,48) (8,91) (9,64) 
(6,84) (7,75) (8,47) (9,87)
```

which obviously means that some thread prints more that 10 keys that I assigned to it. How do I make every thread print exactly 10 keys and values that it is assigned to them and ensure concurrency here?

I am not sure how to test it.

Comment: there are 50 pairs, the keys are within range, random values are whatever. so each one looks good, doesn't it? they write to stdout simultaneously, though.

Comment: I suggest trying `synchronized(System.out)` instead of using `synchronized(this)`. If you do that, your threads will at least share the same lock.

Comment: The threads are generating only 10 entries. You should synchronize on something that's shared across the threads. either a static key or the class itself. That is the issue here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your threads don't share any internal state. They're working fine, but the output is interleaved.

For instance if you used a `StringBuilder` to do the I/O in one operation, you should see correct output.

```
        StringBuilder buff = new StringBuilder();
        for (int i : storage.keySet()) {
            buff.append("(" + i + "," + storage.get(i) + ") ");
        }
        System.out.println(buff);
```

There is no good reason for `Server` to be `Runnable`, or even to create any instances of it.

You do not share any of the maps. If you did, then you would also want to share a common lock, but this is not the usual way to use `ConcurrentMap`.

Comment: This is a query for learning purposes. Since the run block of Server1 is synchronized, it means that only one thread can access the synchronized block at a single given point of time. That being the case how is it possible for the output to be interleaved?

Comment: @Vinnie One thread for each `Object` locked. Each thread has a different object.

Answer (score 0):

All you had to do was `synchronized (Server1.class)` as that is common across threads. Not the `instance`

Here is the verified output:

> (0,75) (1,9) (2,61) (3,73) (4,55) (5,34) (6,34) (7,74) (8,41) (9,0)
>
> (0,30) (1,42) (2,46) (3,66) (4,12) (5,17) (6,62) (7,59) (8,74) (9,4)
>
> (0,50) (1,16) (2,29) (3,74) (4,68) (5,42) (6,33) (7,91) (8,25) (9,7)
>
> (0,49) (1,10) (2,39) (3,94) (4,12) (5,55) (6,54) (7,89) (8,21) (9,75)
>
> (0,77) (1,10) (2,37) (3,32) (4,73) (5,39) (6,64) (7,98) (8,96) (9,44)